# The process of complex integration is the same as that of real integration

Tags: complex-integration

If I compute the complex integral (along $\gamma(t)=e^{it}\,;\;t\in[0,\pi]$)
\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma z^2dz &=\left[\frac{z^3}{3}\right]_\gamma \\
&=\left[\frac{e^{3it}}{3}\right]_0^\pi=-2/3
\end{align*}
But if I expand the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma z^2dz&=\int_\gamma([x^2-y^2]+i2xy)(dx+idy)\\
&=\left[\frac{x^3}{3}-2xy^2+i\left(2x^2y-\frac{y^3}{3}\right)\right]_\gamma\\ \label{1}
&=-2/3
\end{align*}

What confuses me is when I expand $\frac{z^3}{3}$
\begin{align*}
\frac{(x+iy)^3}{3}\neq \frac{x^3}{3}-2xy^2+i\left(2x^2y-\frac{y^3}{3}\right)
\end{align*}

But the result of the integral is the same, Why it is true?

Comment: Perhaps there are some trigonometric identities that happen when you replace x and y with cosines and sines? Try expressing both sides in terms of t and see if the inequality holds then.

Comment: I feel like there might be something going on with Cauchy Reimann and gamma that makes it so these expressions will still evaluate to the same thing.